# How to set an image to the size of a button in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, button, javafx

I'm using JavaFX for school and I need to display a picture on a button when I click on it. My problem is that the image is bigger than the button and then everything is horrible. I have seen multiples post on how to fit a image to a button and I came with that code

```
Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TP2/ressources/flag.png"));
ImageView img = new ImageView(imageOk);
img.setFitWidth(100);
img.setFitHeight(100);
btn.setGraphic(img);
```

When I create the button I use `setPrefSize(50, 50);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fitWidthProperty` and `fitHeightProperty` of the ImageView and bind them to the `widthProperty` and `heightProperty` of the button:

```
img.fitWidthProperty().bind(btn.widthProperty());
img.fitHeightProperty().bind(btn.heightProperty());
```

This will cause the ImageView to have the same size as the button every time.

This can cause the image to be stretched. To prevent this you can use `setPreserveRatio` on the image:

```
img.setPreserveRatio(true);
```

Here is the complete example code:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setPrefSize(50, 50);
Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("yes.png"));
ImageView img = new ImageView(imageOk);
img.setPreserveRatio(true);
img.fitWidthProperty().bind(btn.widthProperty());
img.fitHeightProperty().bind(btn.heightProperty());
btn.setGraphic(img);
```